# Site Column Default value not displaying

Tags: list, site-column

In my Sharepoint site I have lots of lists all containing a site Column "Action to be taken". This is a choice for the user and I have selected the default value "1. Not Checked Yet", however this value is not displayed across my lists.

Has anyone come across this type of problem before.

Comment: Were the lists created before the default value was set on the site column, or after?

Comment: The lists were created after the column

Comment: Default Value will get displayed (selected) when you create a new item. Already created list items will have no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Content Type (which has the site column in question) the default content type.

Source - http://sweechingho.blogspot.com/2008/07/sharepoint-site-column-default-value.html